# PHP Array in to Json and recover data in to webpage

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am having trouble with Json Array.

My **json data**:

```
{
    "res": ["000000000078", "00000001", "1367771147", "das ist mail text",
            "000000000080", "00000001", "1367771147", "das ist mail text", 
            "000000000081", "00000001", "1367771147", "das ist mail text", 
            "000000000082", "00000001", "1367771147", "das ist mail text", 
            "000000000083", "00000001", "1367771147", "das ist mail text",
            "000000000085", "00000001", "1367771147", "das ist mail text", 
            "000000000090", "00000001", "1367771147", "das ist mail text", 
            "000000000091", "00000001", "1367771147", "das ist mail text", 
            "000000000092", "00000001", "1367771147", "das ist mail text", 
            "000000000093", "00000001", "1367771147", "das ist mail text"],
    "fvdfvv": "sdfsd"
}
```

Calling that stuff in **html site**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "mtable.php",
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            var id_mail = result.res[0];
            var id_user = result.res[1];
            var mail_datesent = result.res[2]
            var mail_text = result.res[3]

            $.each(result.res, function (i, data) {
                console.log(data);

                $('#example').append("<tr><td><b>id: </b>" + id_mail + "</td><td><b> leistung: </b>" + id_user + "</td><td><b> temp: </b>" + mail_datesent + "</td><td><b> Text: </b>" + mail_text + "</td></tr><br />");

            });
        }
    });
});
```

I did not put all rows in to Html echo. The Problem is that he loads the Array and puts it in to the table. But he loops on first line.

**Example out**:

```
<p>id: 000000000078  leistung: 00000001  temp: 1367771147  Text: das ist mail text </p>
<p>id: 000000000078  leistung: 00000001  temp: 1367771147  Text: das ist mail text </p>
<p>id: 000000000078  leistung: 00000001  temp: 1367771147  Text: das ist mail text </p>
```

I was also trying:

```
success: function(result) {
             var allresult = result.res
             $('#example').html(  allresult  );

             alert(allresult);
             //$("#notice_div").hide();  
         }
     });
})
```

Here json loads the whole table but I need the rows to put it correctly in to datatable. I am sure that the code above won't work with JQuery.datatables, right?

Comment: What exactly is the question here? What is the expected outcome?

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please try to write a somehow readable English with showing some effort in correct grammar.

Comment: srry for my bad englisch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you should change your JSON data so that every email result is separate. But if you are stuck with this data, then I suppose you should do something like this:

```
for(var i=0,l = result.res.length;i<l ;i+=4){
   var id_mail = result.res[i]; 
   var id_user = result.res[i+1]; 
   var mail_datesent = result.res[i+2] 
   var mail_text = result.res[i+3]
   $('#example').append("<tr><td><b>id: </b>"+id_mail+"</td><td><b> leistung: </b>"+id_user+"</td><td><b> temp: </b>"+mail_datesent+"</td><td><b> Text: </b>"+mail_text+ "</td></tr><br />");
}
```

Comment: Thats work perefktly :) it cant be that the work with json harder then php? is there a better way ? :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of building you **res** as a `simple array`, build it as **array of objects**,

where each object in the array is the email recipient.

The way you are executing your code currently, you seem to be pre evaluating the values in the first 4 indexed items.

So for each item you see a repeated sequence that would be the total length of the array.
Somewhat in these lines

```
{
    "res": [{
              "id" : "000000000078",
              "leistung" : "00000001",
              "temp" :"1367771147",
              "text" : "das ist mail text"
             }, {
              "id" : "000000000079",
              "leistung" : "00000001",
              "temp" :"1367771147",
              "text" : "das ist mail text"
             },{
              "id" : "000000000080",
              "leistung" : "00000001",
              "temp" :"1367771147",
              "text" : "das ist mail text"
             },
          ],
    "fvdfvv": "sdfsd"
}
```

So that your data is more organized.

Comment: +1 I believe that is the right way to treat that kind of data.

Comment: yes thats right: but when creating better Array in php, stucking in read it, so i get always object not definied or komplette lenght error in JQuery.js or else `[{"data":{"id_mail":"000000000078","id_user":"00000001","mail_datesent":"1367771147","mail_betreff":"Mail betreff 023401","mail_text":"das ist mail text","mail_read":"0","mail_sender":"robert"}} that other one